# what are the types of error messages that dd outputs?

Tags: linux, dd, man, stderr

What are the error messages that dd outputs? I tried to look at manual, but it does not say anything about it. Or I do not know how to look at manuals (man).

Edit: OK. I'll make it simple: what error is produced to terminal if dd encounters bad block/sectors causing read error? Does it just print no error message?

Comment: Why do you need to know? What *actual* problem are you trying to solve? All your questions revolve around the same thing – maybe just tell us what you are really up to?

Comment: @slhck I edited my question.

Comment: That's no different than your previous question. What I meant was, why do you have so many questions about `dd`? What do you need to do with it since you're asking so many specific questions? If you give more context about what you *really* need (e.g. you need to write some kind of script), you will get better answers.

Comment: @slhck I just ran dd without conv=sync,noerror when backing up hard disk so I am worrying that things might be missing from the outoput file (which would mean size difference) because of hard disk's bad sectors that might have been there causing read error. That's why I am wondering if dd notifies me of these types of errors, because I didn't see any error.

Comment: I see. However in that case, having one question about that one problem you're facing is more than enough. Please refrain from creating additional ones in that direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It would be quite time-consuming to compile a comprehensive list.  If you're really interested, you could try looking at [dd's source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/dd.c;hb=HEAD).  Try searching for '`error (`' (although that's not guaranteed to get everything, it'll give you a flavour of what `dd` might say in the event of unpleasantness).